# How to use x-editable with Bootstrap 3.5 and latest versions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable, jquery-select2-4

I am using Bootstrap 3.5, Select2 4.0 and X-editable 1.5.1.

I am facing a lot of issues since x-editable is no longer maintained to suit Bootstrap 3.5 and Select2 4.0. I have problems in select2 (tags mode), using popovers to edit, etc.

Is there any better alternative to x-editable library (which is actively updated)? (Don't mind if it is jQuery or jQuery UI based)

I know its not a programmatic question but I have been banging my head with so much incompatibilities.

**UPDATE:** To add to this pain, even latest versions of typeaheadjs is not compatible with xeditable and I had to go with older ones.

Can some please help point out how to use x-editable with Bootstrap 3.5 and latest versions?

Comment: While this maybe off-topic as such, it does raise a good exception.... As i was about to explore using this or the concept at least and looking at the change log, changed my mind straight away... As usual, i will end up writing my own js or extension to know its reliable and maintainable without all the bloats